# e.Graphics.DrawImage is changing my barcode image

Tags: c#, itext, barcode, drawimage, printdocument

I generated a barcode image with iTextSharp:

```cs
public static Image GetCodigoBarra(TipoCodigoBarra tipoCodigo, string valorAcodificar)
{
    Barcode brCD;
    switch (tipoCodigo)
    {
        case TipoCodigoBarra.CODE128: brCD = new Barcode128(); brCD.CodeType = Barcode.CODE128; break;
        case TipoCodigoBarra.EAN13: brCD = new BarcodeEAN(); brCD.CodeType = Barcode.EAN13; break;
        case TipoCodigoBarra.EAN8: brCD = new BarcodeEAN(); brCD.CodeType = Barcode.EAN8; break;
        case TipoCodigoBarra.UPCA: brCD = new Barcode128(); brCD.CodeType = Barcode.UPCA; break;
        case TipoCodigoBarra.UPCE: brCD = new Barcode128(); brCD.CodeType = Barcode.UPCE; break;
        default: brCD = new Barcode128(); brCD.CodeType = Barcode.CODE128; break;
    }
    brCD.ChecksumText = true;
    brCD.GenerateChecksum = true;
    brCD.Code = valorAcodificar;
    return brCD.CreateDrawingImage(System.Drawing.Color.Black, System.Drawing.Color.White);
}
```

I call this method with this:

```cs
Image brCode = GetCodigoBarra(TipoCodigoBarra.CODE128, "10004523");
```

I want to print this in a `PrintDocument` using:

```cs
e.Graphics.DrawImage(brCode, -100-brCode.Width*0.5f, -(PosicionY + altoArial * fuente18B.Size * 3));
```

but look what I get instead a clean barcode (screenshot from the resulting pdf):

[image]

Before I make `DrawImage` to `PrintDocument` I make a jpg copy of the image:

```cs
brCode.Save(@"C:\Users\account_name\Downloads\brcode.jpg");
```

and I get this image, which is correct:

[image]

What's wrong? How do I get rid of the grayscale?

Comment: Try turning off any anti-aliasing.

Comment: Is antialiasing on? `e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None` will turn it off.

Comment: Hi, i don't have any instructions on antialiasing but i have added your code and there is no change. I have also tried another printers with the same result.